# Java List<CAP#1> cannot be converted to List<Object> with Java 10

Tags: java

I had some Java code written that worked perfectly with Java 9, but now I have upgraded to Java 10 it won't compile, saying:

`error: incompatible types: List<CAP#1> cannot be converted to List<Object>`
`List<Object> x509DataContentList = x509Data.getContent();`

This is my code:

```
   static class MyKeySelector extends KeySelector
  {
    final Key key;
    public MyKeySelector(Key key)
    {
      this.key = key;
    }
    @Override
    public KeySelectorResult select(KeyInfo keyInfo,
        Purpose purpose,
        AlgorithmMethod method,
        XMLCryptoContext context) throws KeySelectorException
    {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      List<XMLStructure> content = keyInfo.getContent();
      for (XMLStructure xmlStructure : content)
      {
        if(xmlStructure instanceof X509Data) {
          X509Data x509Data = (X509Data) xmlStructure;
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          List<Object> x509DataContentList = x509Data.getContent();
```

Any idea how to fix this error?  I don't really know Java very well at all, and this error just seems like gobbledygook to me!

Comment: Are you sure x509Data.getContent() returns List<Object>?

Comment: No, but it used to work fine before, so maybe?

Comment: Remember that List<X> isn't subclass of List<Object> even if X is subclass of Object. I'd suggest trying. List<?> x509DataContentList = x509Data.getContent();

Comment: Yes, that seems to work, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<?> x509DataContentList = x509Data.getContent()
```

Above code works for me.

Comment: Even though this is definitely a necro-answer, at least it gives some closure...